# jquery .contextMenu (by SWIS) prevents Enter key function on "text" type input; want to re-enable

Tags: jquery, text, input, contextmenu, enter

I am using the SWIS built .contextMenus for jQuery.  Everything seems to work.  By default, they have text type inputs ignore [ENTER] key press.  I want that to 'submit' the input, and/or close the menu, or similar.
I have seen lots of suggestions - none seem to work.  The following is the code for the "recolor" key item on the menu - with which I want to allow the user to input a new color code for the selected item. The shown trigger('click') was found from another suggestion - it fails.  I am using Chrome.  When I replace the given keyCode 13 stuff with $.contextMenu('destroy') then it "works", but all menus are then disabled.  The selector ".context-menu-one" is correct for my menus. I just want to close the currently open menu.

```
                    "recolor": 
                    {
                        name: "Color Code", 
                        type: "text", 
                        value: "#000000", 
                        events: 
                        {
                            keyup: function(e) 
                            {
                                // add some fancy key handling here?
                                window.console && console.log('key: '+ e.keyCode);
                                if (e.keyCode == 13)
                                {
                                    $('.context-menu-one').trigger('click');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

By the way, I searched the .js library and found this section...

```
                case 13: // enter
                    handle.keyStop(e, opt);
                    if (opt.isInput) {
                        if (opt.$selected && !opt.$selected.is('textarea, select')) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (typeof opt.$selected !== 'undefined' && opt.$selected !== null) {
                        opt.$selected.trigger('mouseup');
                    }
                    return;
```

When I alter this file to rem out the e.preventDefault (or even the entire code 13 section), the enter key is still ignored in the menu!  I was sure that move would work... but alas, no.

As, always, so much thanks for any help.